# After installing debian 6 on my laptop along with windows 7 64bit , my laptop only boots to debian what should I do?

Tags: windows-7, grub, multi-boot, debian-squeeze

I've installed Debian 6 32bit on the same HDD but different partition along with Windows 7 64bit, and now my laptop only boots to Debian 6 where I want both Windows / Debian.

How can I edit GRUB to show both windows and debian?

Answer (score 0):

Look in /boot/grub/menu.lst, there is an example setup with windows on the first disk first partition `(hd0,0)` and Linux on the first disk second partition `(hd0,1)`. Beyond that you see the active entries. If windows is on the first partition, your active part should look similar like this:

```
title         Windows 7
root          (hd0,0)
chainloader   +1

title         Debian Linux Default
...
```

(Don't modify the Linux entry)

With the next boot it should appear in the boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have corrupted your Master Boot Record - open up the terminal and run the following commands:

```
terminal-prompt>su
//you will be asked to give the root password
terminal-prompt>update-grub
//grub will once again take a look at the OSs on your HDD
//it will probably find the windows install this time
```

That's it! If it works, Grub will tell you it found Windows 7. Then you simply need to restart and boot to windows :) I suspect the above will also work with `sudo update-grub` but I did not try that...